# CNTLM for Windows stopped working

Tags: windows, proxy, authentication, cntlm

I have Windows 8.1 64bit and CNTLM version 0.92.3.
It was working perfectly on my machine before it stopped working 1 week ago.
The service still starts correctly but when i use cntlm proxy this message shows up in firefox:

```
The proxy moz-proxy://localhost:3128 is requesting a username and password. The site says: "Cntlm for parent"
```

What could be the problem, i have not changed any settings in cntlm.ini. it is still in the same state when it was working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You haven't specified either user or password for cntlm and it needs them to connect to the parent proxies, or
2. Cntlm tries to connect to the parent proxy(ies) and the connection is refused because the user and/or password you provided in the `cntlm.ini` file are incorrect.